# C# - Marshalling a const char* return value from dll

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have a function in a dll with the following identifier.

```
const char* function(void)
```

The DLL allocates the string on the heap and expects it only to be read.   I have tried the following to import the function but am getting an access violation

```
[DllImport("great.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
                        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)
]
public static extern string function();
```

How do I handle this properly

Error message:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Comment: The marshaler assumes the DLL allocated the string on the com heap and so calls CoTaskMemFree on the returned pointer. Clearly the DLL did not do that. The question is, how is that string allocated? You need to understand that before proceeding.

Comment: I don't think so. But if it's good enough for you.

Comment: also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings

Comment: You can't hope to make progress until you address the question I asked in my first question.

Comment: That's how it is encoded. How is it allocated? In the stack? The heap? Which heap? These details need to be in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the text in the question
""With other functions with the same parameter type, I have been able to use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] to handle it, but this will not work for return values."

quoting this from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute?view=netframework-4.7

```
//Applied to a return value.
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String GetMessage()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

update: keeping this in case it is helpful for others searching about "MarshalAs" and return values, since the author of the question has already solved their issue as they comment above

Comment: btw, are you aware of http://www.pinvoke.net/ website?

Comment: Have you ever though that somebody may talk to this C# method from the native code side? (say callback to it or call it directly?). The even funnier thing is that you haven't noticed that this is Microsoft's sample code, not mine and the answer to the original question was about the "[return: ...]" in fact, since the question was mentioning being able to use MarshalAs, but not with return values. Please read more carefully before criticizing

Comment: Then you'd need to be using something like Robert Giesecke's UmmanagedExports. Which you aren't. Because that would be wrong anyway. Because here we have managed code calling unmanaged code.

Comment: Read the article quoted and complain to Microsoft if you think this is wrong sample. I was only replying on the mention of "MarshalAs" for return values in the original question. Couldn't post as plain comment since it doesn't allow any formatting

Comment: Microsoft has feedback link usually at the bottom of such articles, go complain to them first

Comment: What is especially egregious about this answer is that, even if we applied the attribute to an external declaration, you are matching 8 bit `char` with 16 bit `LPWStr`. Not to mention the fact that you skipped over the call to `CoTaskMemFree` that the marshaler makes to deallocate the returned string. The fact that Microsoft gets it wrong doesn't absolve you of anything. If you don't understand what I say in this comment, you aren't ready to answer this sort of question.

Comment: again, this is quotation to point to "[return: MarshalAs(...)]" syntax, not suggesting they use it literally. The article writes "Some parameters and return values have different default marshaling behavior when used with COM interop or platform invoke. By default, the runtime marshals a string parameter (and fields in a value type) as a LPStr to a platform invoke method or function. For additional information, see Default Marshaling Behavior." so what I read is that the marshaler (the P/Invoke one or the COM interop one) should take care of the low level details.

Comment: also, at https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20978933/COM-interop-do-i-need-to-CoTaskMemFree.html I read "If you use the marhalling Attributes you don't need to manage the memory yourself. (It works only if no conventions are violated, else you have to do it manually. But in this case it should work propertyl.)" and that's what I would expect when using attributes (a more aspect-oriented style /  declarative programming)

Comment: In case of return value marshaled as `LPStr` or `LPWStr` the marshaller assumes the string is allocated on the COM heap and deallocates. Is that the case here? Did you know that fact? You ought to. And the default for `string` is `LPStr` so there's not even any need to apply `MarshalAs` to get the right character set. Are you interested in dealing with your pride, or do you want to get this right?

Comment: you keep on commenting on a quoted part of the Microsoft code that was there to point the "[return: MarshalAs(...)]" as a reply to the "With other functions with the same parameter type, I have been able to use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] to handle it, but this will not work for return values." that the original question writes. If you were commenting that I should have sent that as a comment instead of an answer I'd agree, but as I wrote already, comments are a bit limited in prose

Comment: I suggest you address the question

Comment: added some text to clarify the context, hope it sounds better now

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis You did explicitly address & answer the question I asked, and I appreciate it.  Whether my question related to the problem I ran into is another issue.  I am still trying to make sure I am marshaling it correctly

Comment: btw, the "Robert Giesecke's UmmanagedExports" mentioned above, seem to be useful if one wants to add entries callable from unmanaged code to a managed assembly DLL (export points) from what I understand. The DllExport attribute it defines shouldn't be needed if you just want to make a callback function that you pass from the managed side to the unmanaged code side in order for it to call you back later on

Comment: @kealist just in case, also make sure that the native side uses Cdecl calling convention and not something else (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx for example) - that is since you write "CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl"

Comment: ...and also check how calling conventions behave with x64 code if you're into such - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx. Note that C# projects have an option to force 32-bit build from what I remember